# flake8 --diff not working from directory except repository root

Tags: bash, git, flake8

Repository tree is shown as above

```
.
├── __init__.py
└── source
    ├── __init__.py
    └── main.py
```

**main.py** file

```
def add(a, b):
    return a + b
```

When I change file `main.py` to

```
def add(a, b):
    return a +b
```

and make `git diff -U0 | flake8 --diff` from repository root it shows me

> source/main.py:2:15: E225 missing whitespace around operator

but when I make the same command from `source` folder it doesn't show anything

At the same moment `git diff -U0` shows an identical result inside root repository and `source` folder

```
diff --git a/source/main.py b/source/main.py
index 4693ad3..fd47298 100644
--- a/source/main.py
+++ b/source/main.py
@@ -2 +2 @@ def add(a, b):
-    return a + b
+    return a +b
```

Comment: Does flake8 need the path relative to the current working directory, rather than to the top of the repository work-tree? If so, see the `--relative[=<path>]` flag.

Comment: @torek indeed! `git diff -U0 --relative=source/ | flake8 --diff` helps in this case. Please write this like an answer to the question so I can mark it as an answer.

Comment: You should not need the `=source` part, since wherever it is you're running this command, that's what you want for the `--relative`.

Comment: @torek oops. yes. but please update in answer `-U0` instead `--U0`

Comment: fixed (it's way too easy to overdash, especially when all the other options are two-dash)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently flake8 would like the paths in the output to be relative to the current working directory.  That means you want:

```
git diff -U0 --relative | flake8 --diff
```

since by default, `git diff` produces:

```
--- a/source/main.py
+++ b/source/main.py
```

as in your example.  Adding `--relative` (which defaults to the current directory) should produce:

```
--- a/main.py
+++ b/main.py
```

instead.

Comment: Note that flake8 --diff got deprecated